# How to get the Qiskit textbook widgets working?

Tags: qiskit

For example, when trying to run

```
from qiskit_textbook.widgets import gate_demo
gate_demo(gates='pauli')
```

in Jupyter notebook or a script, the output I get is

HBox(children=(Button(description='X', layout=Layout(height='3em'), style=ButtonStyle()), Button(...

Image(value=b'\x89PNG\r\n\xla\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02...

Comment: Do you get this output in both a script and a jupyter notebook? I just ran the code in a notebook and the output was the correct graphic. I'm not sure if this will run in a regular script as the graphic stays open and is interactive. It most likely needs to be run in a notebook. If you are running it in a notebook, try running the cell again, the graphic might come up after a second run.

Comment: @MatthewStypulkoski Yes, I get the same output in both ways. Running the cell again doesn't seem to make a difference, either.